# How to use passive bonuses from weapon enchantments?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Basically, how do I have to hold/store/whatever the items to get whatever passive bonuses they grant. For example, Eager and Warning provide passive initiative bonuses. I think one of these actually requires you to pull it out and wield it to use it, but assume it didn't have that requirement explicitly mentioned. (As I'm wanting some rules for all such bonuses on weapons, not just that one.)

And what if you put the enchantments on ammunition?

Comment: Do you have links to the relevant passive bonus descriptions? Every ability I've seen like this in both D&D and pathfinder requires you to wield the weapon/wear the armour - in which case it is clear.

Answer (score 7):

## The rules don't cover this explicitly; ask the DM

Many magic items—including weapons—require the items to be *possessed* (as in *acquired* not, like, *The Exorcist*) by a creature to supply their bonus or activate their effects (cf. [*cloak of charisma*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#cloakofCharisma), [*luck blade*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#luckBlade), [*orb of storms*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#orbofStorms), [*pearl of power*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#pearlofPower)). Usually this is taken to mean *attended* by the item's owner—a term which, itself, is occasionally problematic—, but at the least means close enough to the owner's person that the item somehow shares the owner's saving throws. Most DMs require the item actually *be* with the owner rather than, for example, stored in his castle's treasure room on his personal demiplane while the owner's off exploring Castle Greyhawk.

Further, many items are either [command-word](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#commandWord) activated or [use-activated](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#useActivated). One must *hold* a command-word activated item to activate it (that includes the aforementioned [*orb of storms*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#orbofStorms) and [*pearl of power*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#pearlofPower)) but need only use appropriately a use-activated item (like wearing on your shoulders the aforementioned [*cloak of charisma*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#cloakofCharisma)). Technically, the aforementioned [*luck blade*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#luckBlade)'s power of good fortune *should* require holding the luck blade and activating the ability by taking a standard action to speak the command word, but I've never heard of a DM requiring this given the good fortune's ability to manipulate the metagame.

As most weapon special abilities are use-activated ("swing a sword"), wielding the weapon is *usually* how the weapon special ability is used, but the DM may rule that mere possession is sufficient *or* that the weapon special ability must be activated with a command word. It's his call.

Specifically, a weapon with the weapon special ability *eager* (*MIC* 34) (+1 bonus) must be wielded to grant its user its bonuses, while a weapon with the weapon special ability *warning* (*MIC* 46) (+1 bonus) must be held.

### A note about ammunition

The game was always a little fuzzy as to what weapon special abilities can be placed on melee weapons, ranged weapons, and ammunition. For example, arguments raged—and might still—over the viability of the weapon special ability [*spell-storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring) (*DMG* 225) (+1 bonus) when applied to ammunition. At this point in the game's history, it's better to ask the DM if a specific weapon special ability can be applied to ammunition; you'll likely find little guidance from official sources.

Further, the idea sometimes crops up in theoretical optimization circles of using the weapon special ability [*defending*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#defending) (*DMG* 224) (+1 bonus) with quivers of *+1 defending arrows* to gain impressive bonuses. However, according to the rules as written, the weapon special ability *defending* functions when placed on swords *only*, an oft-overlooked or frequently discounted bit of rules goofiness which exists as far back as the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) and persists in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2013).

Comment: @SangoProductions I'd be happy to update the answer to address a specific gimmick if you want. The initial question seemed like it was trying to get away with something without mentioning exactly what it was trying to get away with. I'd kinda like to be in on the plan.

Comment: It was a general question because the on-use stuff like Flaming is kinda obvious that it would only ever work if you swung the weapon (or however you use it). The passive stuff - could you just tape it to your forehead and call it a day? was the basis of the question

Comment: *Defending* works on any weapon; nothing says otherwise, and it starts out with “A *defending* weapon,” after all. It’s just that the bonus you get to AC is equal to “the sword’s enhancement bonus.” Which sword? *The* sword, man.

Comment: @KRyan Hey, man, if you can read that as the *defending* weapon getting its bonus from the Platonic ideal of **the sword** or something instead of from the weapon special ability *defending* that's been applied to the sword you're now wielding, you're demonstrating a degree of cognitive flexibility that I can but envy.